# Basic program with objects (java)

Tags: java, object

I want to create program that ask for name, surname and age and then will print in on my screen. But I'm experimenting with "toString" method and objects.

When I run my program, I type name, surname and age, it interrupt and show me message:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != tutorial35Composition.Banana
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at tutorial35Composition.Apple.toString(Apple.java:13)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
    at tutorial35Composition.Main.main(Main.java:24)
"
```

code is:

```
package tutorial35Composition;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        String surname;
        int age;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type your name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type your surname: ");
        surname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Type your age: ");
        age = input.nextInt();

        Banana banana = new Banana(age);
        Banana banan = banana;
        Apple apple = new Apple(name,surname,banan);
        Apple appl;
        appl = apple;
        System.out.println(appl);
    }

}


package tutorial35Composition;

public class Apple {
    String Name;
    String Surname;
    Banana Age;
    public Apple(String name,String surname,Banana age){
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Age = age;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Your name is %s, your surname is %s and your age is %02d", Name, Surname, Age);
    }
}

package tutorial35Composition;

public class Banana {
    int age;
    public Banana(int Age){
        age = Age;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String Age2;
        Age2 = age + "";
        return Age2;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because you `Banana` is not an integer. Are you sure that Calling your age a `Banana` makes sense?

Comment: Sorry for not appropriate names, I'm only learning Java and experimenting. And thank you for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't print a `Banana` as an integer, but you can print the `age` in that class.

```
    return String.format("Your name is %s, your surname is %s and your age is %02d", 
           Name, Surname, Age.age);
```

BTW you should start variable names with a lower case letter. e.g. `name`, `surname`, and `age`

Comment: To add on a small piece... When I am passing variables through a Method I use ‘_var‘ to represent the temp variable and 'var' to represent the variable to set‘

Comment: @R.Hull my IDE shows these in a different colours which ok for me.

Answer (score 4):

The API for Java `String` format indicate the `%d` represents:

> The result is formatted as a decimal integer

**A banana is not an integer** (so thrilled I got to say that finally).

You can implement a getter for your `age` property of `Banana`, and invoke that instead of passing the whole `Banana` instance to your formatter.

API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to print an object not its members you can do this way or you could use a getter method to get the values.

```
public String toString()
{
  return String.format("Your name is %s, your surname is %s and your age is 
  %02d", Name, Surname, Age.age);
}
```

Using Getters in banana class

```
public int getAge(){
    return age;
 }
```